Upgrade to Fedora 39 Workstation has bricked my system
I tried to upgrade using the recommended 'dnf system-upgrade` route from 37-39 but the reboot seemed to do nothing.
I tried then to upgrade just to 38 but now I just see a spinner with the bios logo and a fedora logo.
I am in possession of a bootable Fedora 39 image on a flash drive and I have tried checking the file systems but that has not helped. I would be happy if I could upgrade from the liveCD but that does not appear to be an option.
Given the complete lack of clues as to why the machine will not boot, I could do with some advice on next steps.

on further investigation I find that the filesystem in question is btrfs. I am attempting recovery now, but so far it has just created a single empty folder home/hugh

yes - if only I can retrieve some files first ...

I had supposed I could use the LiveCD to extract files and paste them to the network somewhere but - and I guess this explains what has happened - I do not seem to be able to mount the relevant partition

I have backups, but there is a VM on there that would be very sweet if I could restore it and would save quite a bit of time.  I am running a btrfs restore now, let us see what happens.

First recover files. Try booting from any live OS that can read your drive's BtrFS file system. Live Ubuntu, Trinity Rescue Kit, or an alternative, should be able to mount that drive if it works and transfer files to another. Since you could not find any files, try a recovery tool such as EaseUS BtrFS Recovery Software, or see this SuperUser answer.
However, you state,  " I do not seem to be able to mount the relevant partition," in a comment (which belongs in the edited question, along with the drive type: SSD? HDD?). Perhaps the drive is dead. Hard disk drives tend to fail little-by-little, and it might be possible to salvage some data using recovery tools, if checking the disk has not destroyed the data. Solid state drives are usually designed to become read-only near the end of life, and if you're lucky, all data can be recovered... and, as Bob Newhart described a sinking plane, "some of them go down like a rock." If that's the case, salvage what you can from your last disk image or backup on external media.
After disk issues are fixed, remove all partitions and install de novo.

forgive me - I am a programmer and 'don't do' hardware and infrastructure

@HughJones, There's nothing to forgive -- just edit the question to better let us help, and I'll edit the answer as the info is added.

I edited the question a little, but really the correct answer was 'JFDI'.

I successfully restored the data I needed from the drive by booting from the livecd.  Presumably this means that it was the boot partition that had failed because the data was intact as far as I can tell.
One little 'gotcha', though, it took me a while to realise that there was more than one mount point that mentioned 'LiveCD'.  This confused me for a while until I realised that one of them was the data drive I need to use, the other being the flash drive I had booted from.
It made me feel a bit silly but, as Bob Newhart would say 'Don't be silly.  Don't waste your time'.
